# Changing the URL when it loads from iframe

Tags: javascript, php, html, url, iframe

I have 3 following pages

- form123.html ...........  iframe
- form.php     ..................php code
- validate.php.............validating php code

In my form123.html page has iframe which loads from form.php
now the URL  will be http://www.ect.com/form123.html

```
<iframe id="form" src='form.php'
   frameborder='0' 
   height='750' 
   width='100%'
   scrolling='no' >
</iframe>
```

---

From my form.php code it redirects to the validate.php page then, after all the validation done it redirects to the http://www.ect.com/home-mem.php

I reach the home-mem.php page but still the URL will be the same as the starting of iframe

I need to change the URL when it reaches to the home-mem.php page to the proper URL home-mem.php

form123.html page should be completely html....no php

Comment: that link redirects me to searchfusion.com

Comment: Are you doing it for SEO purpose?

Comment: The links was just an examples..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the validation process is successful you can print only a simple JS code which will redirect the entire page where you want like:

```
<script>window.top.location.href = "http://www.ect.com/home-mem.php"</script>;
```

window.top refers to the window object of the page at the top of the frames hierarchy.

Comment: Or, if you want just the parent frame, you can use window.parent.location.href. If you have nested frames, window.top will lead to the highest iframe level. Using parent will lead to the nearest higher level. =)